# How to remove LineItem instance from an order (Spree)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

I'm working with Spree, but I'm not completely familiar with the built-in methods.
I'm trying to make it so that when params[:quantity] == 0, the line_item instance gets deleted and removed from the order. I've tried calling destroy! on the instance but that hasn't worked, as well as a few of the other build in functions.

```
def update
  @order = current_order
  @line_item = Spree::LineItem.find(params[:id])
  @line_item.quantity = params[:quantity]
  @line_item.save
  # can't figure out a way to remove line_item when quantity is set to zero
  @order.update!

  respond_with(@order) do |format|
    format.json{render json: @order}
  end
end
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done almost correct. it requires correction in your code as follows

```
def update
  @order = current_order
  @line_item = Spree::LineItem.find(params[:id])
  @line_item.quantity -= params[:quantity]
  if @line_item.quantity == 0
    @line_item.destroy
  else
    @line_item.save!
  end
  respond_with(@order) do |format|
    format.json{render json: @order}
  end
 end
```